# Autonomous transaction in TopLink

Tags: java, session, toplink, stateless

I am facing a problem, I want to implement autonomous transaction in TopLink, but I am not too sure about if it is possible or not. I have a also worked on hibernate, as we have stateless session there... do we have something same in TopLink...  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without configuring JTA integration the UnitOfWork from TopLink is autonomous.  What specifically are you attempting to do?